# Objects are not shown on the screen, only the outlines

Tags: rendering, objects

[image]

Hello, I have this problem and I don't know what the cause is.
You see, i was using the last blender update (2.93.4LTS) and it worked fine but sometimes it wont start up, and when i was modeling a character the extrudle tool was doing strtange things, and sometimes the object did not allow me to edit.

So i thought "i should download the older version because that worked for me before!"
I downloaded the 2.82a and this happend, i can see only the object outline  but not the object, when i do the rendering to see if its there, theres only the shape but with missing textures. I saw a couple of videos on youtube and they "fixed" the thing with *select other render engine and go to preference* but as you can see, i font have the preference tab on the render engine (not eevee or cycles).

I'm downloading older versions and its the same, the photo its the 2.80 version, my limit its 7.9 and if it doesnt works, i give up.

This is so weird to me because i made things on 2.82a, i made a lightsaber, i practiced sculpting.
You can say its my hardware, wich its probably true, but as i said, i worked fine on 2.82a.

My hardware is AMD A8 8gigs of RAM, no graphics card but the APU can do very basic work.

Sorry to make this so long, but I'm a bit desperate because I have a contest in 5 days and I just have to model the characters.

Comment: it's a driver problem, try a previous one, or try to enable Render > Performance > High Quality Normals option

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I dont kave the option of high quality normals BUT i saw that people have a problem with the current Radeon drivers, so i'm going to downgrade my Adredalin to 20.9.1 and see if it works!